# Consider symplectic vector fields $X,Y$ and a symplectic connection $\nabla$. Is $\nabla_{X}Y$ symplectic?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry, connections, lie-derivative

Consider a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, together with a symplectic connection $\nabla$, *i.e*. a torsion-free connection such that $\nabla{\omega} = 0$. Fix two symplectic vector fields $X$ and $Y$.

Is it true that $\nabla_{X}Y$ is again a symplectic vector field?

I tried with Cartan calculus but I'm stuck, not beeing able to collect the terms in a clever way. Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the suggestion. This is my first appearance in MSE, so every comment is welcomed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider as a counter-example $M = \mathbb{R}^2$, $\omega = dx \wedge dy$, $X = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ (whose Hamiltonian function is $-x^2/2$), $Y = y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ (whose Hamiltonian function is $y^2 /2$) and the (symplectic) connection given by usual (i.e. component-wise) differentiation of vector fields. Then $\nabla_X Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, which is not symplectic as it is not Hamiltonian (or alternatively because it doesn't have vanishing divergence).

Answer (score 3):

As Jordan Payette correctly pointed out, your statement is in general not true. However, 
$$
\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X
$$
is indeed symplectic: since the torsion vanishes, it is equal to
$
[X,Y]
$
and
$$
\mathcal L_{[X,Y]} \omega = \mathcal L_X \mathcal L_Y \omega-\mathcal L_Y \mathcal L_X \omega=0\,.
$$